# Can I stop the "Please Update Your Secure Tab URL" while in sandbox mode?

Tags: facebook

In [Facebook roadmap documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) says:

> Apps on Facebook Authentication and security migration (HTTPS)
>
> All Canvas and Page tab apps must convert to process signed_request (fb_sig will be removed) and obtain an SSL certificate
> for use in ‘Secure Canvas URL’ and ‘Secure Page Tab URL’ **(unless you
> are in Sandbox mode)**. You must provide an SSL certificate in the Dev
> App settings to avoid having your app disabled.

However I have my application in sandbox mode it's telling me to put in a secure url:

> #### Please Update Your Secure Tab URL
>
> To make sure users can view your app over a secure browser connection (https), please visit the developer console to update your Secure Tab URL.

I have also tried turning of secure browsing under my security settings. How can I get it to stop nagging me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, you will have to either buy an SSL certificate, or [create a self signed SLL certificate](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=free%20ssl%20self%20signed).

SSL certificates are relatively inexpensive, but if for whatever reason you need one for free during development then create a self signed certificate. Your web browser will likely display a warning, but after reassuring your browser that everything is fine, your Facebook app will work fine (for development).